# leveraging cross apply for reusing calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2017

I've a productTable from where I'm reading a column, making a calculation and re-using the same calculation going forward.

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable
(
    productName,
    quantity,
    priceInUSD,
    isValidPrice,
    discountDescription
)
SELECT  TOP (1000) WITH TIES
        pt.productName,
        pt.quantity,
        pt.priceInUSD,
        IIF(pt.priceInUSD >= 10000 OR pt.priceInUSD < 0 , 0, 1) AS isValidPrice,
        IIF(isValidPrice > 0, '10% discount allowed', 'Max $100 discount allowed' )
FROM    ProductTable pt
WHERE   pt.type like 'stock product'
ORDER BY pt.purchaseId ASC
```

**Is there a way I can calculate isValidPrice from a column of productTable and use isValidPrice going forward?**

```
    IIF(pt.priceInUSD >= 10000 OR pt.priceInUSD < 0, 0, 1) AS isValidPrice,
    IIF(isValidPrice > 0, '10% discount allowed', 'Max $100 discount allowed' )
```

Comment: Yes, you can. For example, you can join your result with another table (or query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move the expression to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT  TOP (1000) WITH TIES
        pt.productName,
        pt.quantity,
        pt.priceInUSD,
        v.isValidPrice,
        (CASE WHEN v.isValidPrice > 0 THEN '10% discount allowed' ELSE 'Max $100 discount allowed' END)
FROM ProductTable pt CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN pr.priceInUSD >= 10000 OR pr.priceInUSD < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
     ) v(isValidPrice)
WHERE  pt.type like 'stock product'
ORDER BY pt.purchaseId ASC;
```

Note:  I recommend using *standard* SQL syntax instead of bespoke functionality, so I changed the `IIF()` to a `CASE` expression.

Comment: just a follow-up question
`(VALUES (CASE WHEN pr.priceInUSD >= 10000 OR r.priceInUSD < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
     ) v(isValidPrice) `
will this still work if isValidPrice is DATETIME or NVARCHAR

Comment: and I assume 
`pr.priceInUSD >= 10000 OR r.priceInUSD < 0` is typo
of `pt.priceInUSD >= 10000 OR pt.priceInUSD < 0`

Comment: @Rahulsingh You can also put `discountDescription` in a second `APPLY` referencing the first, obviously

Comment: @Rahulsingh . . . As long as the expression is valid, you can include it in the `VALUES()`.  The expression itself is taken from your code, where you have that typo.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you. This is what I was looking for :)